# Where can I find all the loading screen tips?

Tags: mass-effect-3

My computer is unfortunately beefy enough to make me aware that there are loading screen tips without actually giving me enough time to read them.

Is there a compilation of all the loading screen tips? I've read people getting some good tidbits of information relevant to their current progress from the loading screen (like in Skyrim), and I feel like I'm missing out here.

Comment: Don't get upset but... on the loading screens?

Comment: @GnomeSlice ... good job reading the question.

Comment: Jesus Christ, that was terrible.  I can't even be a smartass correctly any more. =[

Comment: Thanks for this!  I have it running from a solid state drive.  The tips during loading may last... 3/4 to 1 second.  It just ends up teasing.. "Squadmates do more damage when ..."  When what!  When do they do more damage!  Now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website RarityGuide.com has compiled a list of tip texts shown during level screens for players with high-performance such as yourself. **Follow [this link](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/1654/1/Mass-Effect-3-Tips-and-Hints/Page1.html) to access the list.**

Here are some examples of the listed tips:

> Shepard's current health bar will regenerate, but already-depleted segments can only be restored by using First Aid from the Power Wheel.
>
> Carrying too many weapons will increase cooldown, effectively slowing down how often you can use powers.
>
> The Widow, Black Widow, and Javelin weapons can fire through enemies and light cover. Mod other weapons, like the Mattock and Claymore, to apply this devastating effect.
>
> Heavy Melee is an effective attack against unarmored or unshielded enemies
>
> Use the First Aid power to resuscitate a fallen squadmate from a distance. This consumes medi-gel. Move to your comrade to resuscitate them without using medi-gel.
>
> Use hard-hitting weapons against armored opponents. Incendiary and armor-piercing ammo also help.
>
> When a Ravager's sac breaks, Swarmers are released. Swarmers are weak, but a group of them can kill or keep shields from regenerating.
>
> Cannibals form armored plating by reclaiming fallen Cannibals and Husks. Shooting these plates deal no damage to the Cannibal until they are blown off
>
> Weapons have thermal clips to prevent overheating. Clips use a universal design, so retrieve compatible clips from combat areas and fallen enemies.

Source: [RarityGuide.com](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/1654/1/Mass-Effect-3-Tips-and-Hints/Page1.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's an exhaustive list, but all of the loading screen tips I've seen have come from the Tips & Help section of the manual ([link to PDF copies](https://help.ea.com/article/mass-effect-3-manuals)).

Edit: As an example, here is the combat tips section from the manual:

- Cerberus Defense: Cerberus uses mobile defenses. Find and destroy the portable generators that power their shield pylons and cover nodes.
- Combat Rolls: Use combat rolls to get quickly in and out of cover.
- Headshots: Headshots inflict superior damage on most targets.
- Heavy Melee: Heavy melee is an effective attack against unarmored or
  unshielded enemies.
- Higher Ground: Watch out for opponents on higher ground! Elevated enemies can shoot
  you even in cover.
- Barrier Engine: Reaper troops protect themselves by deploying barrier generators called Barrier Engines. Target these first.
- Suppress Shields: Keep firing and unleashing powers to prevent enemy shields
  from regenerating.
- Squad Bonus: Squadmates do more damage when ordered to attack a specific target.
- Squad Configuration: Choosing the right squad to complement Shepard’s strengths and
  weaknesses is key. Experiment with squad configurations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the loading screen tips do indeed come from the in-game manual.

Comment: @Sterno well a bunch are mission-specific, so I doubt those are in the manual. These ones seem like they're from the manual though. I guess...never read it.